# When I run a javascript file with node, if an object is exported in the file, node crashes

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
export class SomeClass extends Qu {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

That's the error message in the console

This is an export line in the file:

Comment: use `module.exports = SomeClass;` https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/nodejs-module-exports

Comment: Make sure that either your module has the `.mjs` and not `.js` extension or you put `"type": "module"` in your `package.json` file to have all your `.js` files treated as ES modules.

Comment: @yochanansheinberger Are you a time traveler from the last?